# ¿Es un "hado" un destino necesariamente adverso?

Tags: definiciones, significado, adjetivos, dle

En una conversación que tuve ayer surgió la palabra *hado*, la cual era desconocida para mi interlocutor. Le comenté (acertadamente, como pude comprobar después) que viene del latín *fatum*, de la cual viene también el *fate* inglés. Hoy he consultado la palabra en el DRAE:

> [**hado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JxsZGaS)
>
> Del lat. *fatum*.
>
> 1. m. En la tradición clásica, fuerza desconocida que obra irresistiblemente sobre los dioses, los hombres y los sucesos.
> 2. m. Encadenamiento fatal de los sucesos.

La primera acepción es la que yo esperaba, pero la segunda me descolocó un poco. ¿Un hado es algo fatal? Lo primero que hice fue ver definiciones anteriores de la palabra:

> 1817-1925: Lo que, conforme a lo dispuesto por Dios desde la eternidad, nos sucede con el discurso del tiempo mediante las causas naturales ordenadas y dirigidas por la Providencia.
>
> 1780: Los gentiles entendieron por hado el órden inevitable de las cosas; pero considerado bien, no es otra cosa que la voluntad de Dios, y lo que está determinado en su eternidad sucederá á cada uno.

Es decir, el hecho de incluir el adjetivo "fatal" en la definición es algo bastante moderno, concretamente desde la versión de 1992. Pero luego comprobé la definición de fatal:

> [**fatal**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HffspKE)
>
> Del lat. fatālis.
>
> 1. adj. inevitable.
> 2. adj. Desgraciado, infeliz.
> 3. adj. malo.
> 4. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al hado.
> 5. adj. Der. Dicho de un plazo: improrrogable.
> 6. adv. Rematadamente mal. *Lo hiciste fatal.*

Yo entendería un "hado" como un destino inevitable (acepción 1) e incluso improrrogable (acepción 5), pero no necesariamente malo, como se entendía en las definiciones de antes de 1992. Por tanto, **¿por qué se usa el adjetivo "fatal" en la definición en vez de directamente "inevitable" como antes? ¿Es un "hado" un destino necesariamente adverso?**

Como curiosidad, en la definición de [*fate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fate) tenemos lo siguiente:

> an inevitable and often adverse outcome, condition, or end

Ellos al menos consideran que el destino tiene bastantes probabilidades de ser adverso, pero no siempre. Y en portugués tenemos [*fado*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fado):

> 1. Força superior que se crê controlar todos os acontecimentos.
> 2. Aquilo que tem de acontecer, independentemente da vontade humana.

que tampoco hace mención a que sea fatal o no.

La RAE responde mediante [un tuit](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/773854123879964673) a la pregunta de si el "hado" es un destino necesariamente adverso:

> No necesariamente. Sí, ineludible.

Así que entiendo que el uso de "fatal" está tomado en su primera acepción ("inevitable"). **¿Por qué entonces no se usó directamente "ineludible" como proponen, en vez de "fatal" que puede llevar a equívoco?**

Comment: Parecen ser definiciones mutuamente recursivas, a través de la 4ª definición de `fatal` y la 2ª de `hado`...

Comment: That is interesting as it means _fatal_ is a False Friend since in English fatal is almost always bad as in "fatal accident", "fatal flaw" whereas meaning 1 from the DRAE which you quote and meaning 4 are neutral.

Comment: Naturalmente, *fatal* tiene el mismo origen etimológico que *hado*. Eso ya nos da una pista. Simplemente, con el tiempo se fue asociando lo inevitable a lo funesto. Al fi y al cabo, ¿para qué querríamos evitar algo deseable?

Comment: Más que a lo funesto, yo diría a lo inevitable. La asociación con lo funesto puede ser coyuntural. Ya en la época clásicael destino estaba dictado por Dioses caprichoso y vengativos que se divertían jugando con el destino de los humanos. Y pocas veces era para bien. Si el destino (según se entendía entonces) solía ser adverso, la asociación de ideas tenía que suceder. Pero hado tb era lo que regía las vidas de los héroes, ya que así lo eran por voluntad de los Dioses. Pero estos eran casos excepcionales.

Comment: @fedorqui te agradezco enormemente la intención, esta pregunta me parecía interesante, pero igual puede ser algo complicada de responder. Incluso me atrevería a decir que puede bordear en el off-topic, dado que igual es imposible de responder a menos que hablemos con el académico que incluyó la definición en el diccionario.

Comment: Yo me atrevería a desarrollar una interpretación de esa asociación de ideas. Pero claro, no tendría ningún valor académico. Sería mi interpretación.

Comment: @Laiv hay veces en que las preguntas no tienen por qué tener una base de respaldo, sino simplemente una argumentación convincente. Yo a veces he dado respuestas así, basándome en mis propias ideas o conocimientos. Por eso comentaba, en todo caso, que igual esta pregunta puede ser offtopic, pero si tu argumentación es convincente, con eso me bastaría.

Comment: Empiezo a creer que la pregunta debería ser por qué el DRAE hace la asociación fatal - ineludible. Como si algo adverso no pudiese evitarse. Sin esta asociación, la pregunta de Carlos no tendría lugar. El hado es una víctima colateral de dicha asociación de ideas

Comment: @Laiv yo entendía la asociación al reves: ¿por qué algo ineludible ha de ser fatal? ¿Qué pasa entonces con frases del tipo "que los hados te sean propicios"? ¿Se usaría aquí la primera acepción de "hado"?

Comment: Ambos sentidos pueden conducir a un silogismo. Lo que me lleva a pensar que se haya dado por válido, por tradición o costumbre.

Comment: @angus Creo que la palabra correcta para las dos definiciones sería [*circulares*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9JaWQWh), no [*recursivas*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VXkDTwd). La recursividad aplica el principio de "divide y vencerás", mientras que la circularidad no tiene fin.

Answer (score 4):

La palabra hado es utilizada en la poesía para tratar de expresar algo inevitable y fatal y en general en sentido desgracia. Aunque es posible (y plausible) usarlo alegóricamente en sentido de gracia (el destino también puede traer bondades).

El hado, al ser el destino, se usa también para dar otro nombre a la muerte como la consecuencia última. Por lo tanto debe de tener un matiz fatal a menos que la muerte misma sea un final deseado.

---

En cuánto a la raíz de la palabra, curiosamente, en [Compendio de teología](https://tomasdeaquino.org/compendio-de-teologia/#1) (Cap. 138), la traducción al español propone que **hado** proviene de la palabra latina **fando**: *"unde et fatum a fando est appelatum"*. Sin embargo, el [texto original](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/ott101.html#70233) se refiere a que el destino (*fatum*) está relacionado con la adivinación; lo que nos tre de vuelta a la relación directa entre **fatum** y **destino**. Además, también relaciona la palabra **fatum** con **fortuna** "*Fatum autem non videtur esse nisi in rebus humanis, in quibus est et fortuna*".

En el mismo texto, se señala que **fatum** es usada para referirse a la relación entre el destino y el movimiento de los cuerpos celestes. Este significado niega la actuación de de la divina providencia por lo cual su uso debe ser evitado. Probablemente, esto le dió el tinte negativo a **fatum** y, por consecuencia, a la palabra **hado**.

---

Para finalizar, pongo algunos usos de *hado* en poemas:

```
Este que ves, engaño colorido,
que, del arte ostentando los primores,
con falsos silogismos de colores
es cauteloso engaño del sentido;

éste, en quien la lisonja ha pretendido 
excusar de los años los horrores,
y venciendo del tiempo los rigores
triunfar de la vejez y del olvido,

es un vano artificio del cuidado,
es una flor al viento delicada,
es un resguardo inútil para el hado:

es una necia diligencia errada,
es un afán caduco y, bien mirado,
es cadáver, es polvo, es sombra, es nada.
```

*Sor Juana Inés de la Cruz (Este que ves, engaño colorido…)*

-

```
La estrella, el signo... ¡Ideal!
el Hado infausto... locura;
que para todo mortal
propicia, fácil, igual
en el mundo es la ventura.
Para el monarca opulento,
para el mendigo indigente 
tiene la vida igualmente
un oportuno momento
de sonrisa complaciente. (frag.)
```

*Carolina Coronado (Al hado)*

-

```
¿Tan grande, ¡ay, hado!, mi delito ha sido
que por castigo de él o por tormento
no basta el que adelanta el pensamiento
sino el que le previenes al oído? (frag.)
```

*Sor Juana Inés de la Cruz (Tan grande ¡ay hado! mi delito ha sido)*

Comment: No vendría mal que citases autor y obra de los versos. Por ejemplo: de _La venganza de don Mendo_ de Pedro Muñoz Seca: «¿Camarada vuestro quien ha delinquido?/ Perpetrando un robo me vi sorprendido,/ así plugo al cielo o al **Hado**... o al Hada,/ y no creo Moncada, que ganéis vos nada,/ siendo camarada de quien a su espada/ ha infido, escupido, torcido... y rompido.»